# Can I log request response in Database in Asp.net core Middleware?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, nlog, asp.net-core-middleware

I am creating a Middleware for logging Request and Response, as I am new to this thing, its not clear how to implement it. As I checked some examples I have written the following thing

```
public RequestResponseLogging(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<RequestResponseLogging> logger)
        {
            if (next == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }
```

I found the below example, this is logging whole request and response, but i need to log some of the properties and i need to log it in Database.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
           _logger.LogInformation(await FormatRequest(context.Request));
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

            using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Response.Body = responseBody;

                await _next(context);

                _logger.LogInformation(await FormatResponse(context.Response));
                await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);

            }
        }
```

I tried something like this:

```
RequestData requestData = new RequestData();
            requestData.UserName = context.Request.Headers[UserKey];
            requestData.Token = context.Request.Headers[TokenKey];

            _logger.LogInformation("Request",requestData);

            await _next(context);

            ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
            responseData.Code = context.Response.Headers["Code"];
            responseData.Descirption = context.Response.Headers["Desciption"];
            _logger.LogInformation("Response", responseData);
```

not sure if this is the right way, do I need to add EF in my middleware? All the examples I have seen for nlog are asking to configure it in startup file, but as I need to implement it in Middleware I dont have any startup file its a class library project not API, from API i am calling my Middleware.
Can anybody help me??

Comment: if the logger is already configured to sent to the db then the middle ware has no need for it to be injected

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: Where I need to configure my logger? from my understanding it should be in the api, where i am injecting my middleware.

Comment: check the doc here for an idea https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#writing-middleware

Comment: from your example, like RequestCultureMiddleware i have my middleware, after configuring the logger i need to get the request and response and pass it to the Database in my middleware.